# Vue about Reactivity in Depth, why Vue can detect property addition like this？

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I test an example !
View like these.

```
<el-button type="primary" @click="onAdd">add</el-button>
<div>{{arr[3]}}</div>
<div>{{obj.text}}</div>
<div v-show="obj.text2">{{obj.text2}}</div>

data() {
        return {
            arr: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            obj: {
                text: 1
            }
        };
    },
```

when use like this, view can't update.

```
    methods: {
        onAdd() {
            // this.$set(this.arr, 3, 0);
            this.arr[3] = 0;
            this.obj.text2 = 'text2';
        }
    },
```

but view can update all, i don't know why view depends on obj can update?

```
methods: {
        onAdd() {
            this.$set(this.arr, 3, 0);
            this.obj.text2 = 'text2';
        }
    },
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html and https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Answer (score 2):

demo:

```js
let obj = {}
Reflect.defineProperty(obj, 'text', {
  get() {
    return 'text of obj'
  },
  set(v) {
    console.log('you are changing the text property to ' + v)
  },
  enumerable: true
})
obj.text = 1;
```

We can detect the property of object when you want to change it.That is how the demo above and code below works.

```
        this.obj.text2 = 'text2';
```

However,we can only detect operation like code below partially:

```
        this.arr[3] = 0;
```

because your code could be :

```
        this.arr[100] = 0;
```

which is add a new property to the array.So,in this case,we can't and don't have to detect operation like:

```
        this.arr[num] = 0;
```

because the detection is not complete and so trouble.

Comment: than you. however my confusion is about adding a property of object worked after $set instead of using $set a property of object in method.

Comment: i can directly set an item with the index to change array or  add a property to a object after any $set sentence to update view instead of using $set to all sentence